# How can I determine if local time is adjusted for daylight savings?

Tags: c#, date, time, dst

Is it possible to know if local time is daylight savings adjusted?

Is it possible to know if the local time on machine is correct?

I guess pretty weird stupid questions (assuming no internet connection), but you never know!!

Comment: If you have more than one you could compare them. Assuming you don't just glance at your watch. :)

Comment: thanks Tony.. could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Internet access is irrelevant. What you are doing is getting is getting a time you can trust to check against one you don't. So to compare times you need one machine on your network you can trust. If you had one you could set up a TimeServer and never worry about this stuff again...

Comment: thank you.. i like the idea.. trusted timeserver + TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingsTime(DateTime.Now) as Reed suggested..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingsTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460642.aspx)`(DateTime.Now)` to check to see if the current time is being adjusted.

Comment: thank you Reed.. but that "indicates whether a specified date and time falls in the range of daylight saving time for the time zone of the current TimeZoneInfo object."(msdn).. so it doesn't actually tell me if it is adjusted or not??

Comment: @user441660 If you're trying to find out if the current time, right now, is adjusted - this should tell you (because I'm feeding it `DateTime.Now`).  This method lets you check to see if any specific date should be adjusted - if you pass "now", you can check to see if the current time is set to be adjusted or not.

Answer (score 0):

I find most implementations of DST add/take away an hour from the GMT offset when calculating time, for example, Sydney Australia would be +10 GMT without DST and +11 GMT with DST